# iOS @IBDesignable autorefresh UILabel params as title, font, color

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I'm working on a feature, that I can set my custom style on UILabel (by taping name of style). I have a simple code for this:

```
struct Style {
    var fontName: String!
    var fontSize: CGFloat!
    var color: UIColor!
    var styleName: String!
    var font: UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: self.fontName, size: self.fontSize)!
    }

    init(styleName: String, fontName: String!, fontSize: CGFloat!, color: UIColor!) {
        self.fontName = fontName
        self.fontSize = fontSize
        self.color = color
    }

    var desc: String {
        return "Style: \(styleName)"
    }
}



let dictStyle: [String: Style] = [
                "normal": Style(styleName: "normal", fontName: "HelveticaNeue-Light", fontSize: 20, color: UIColor.red),
                "bold": Style(styleName: "bold", fontName: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", fontSize: 30, color: UIColor.black)
            ]

@IBDesignable class Label: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var style: String = "normal" {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        self.text = "\(style)" // there is normal or bold

        if let color = dictStyle[self.style]?.color {
            self.textColor =  color
        }
        if let font = dictStyle[self.style]?.font {
            self.font = font
        }
        if let name = dictStyle[self.style]?.styleName {
            self.text =  name
        }
    }
}
```

and it's work ok, but I would like to automatic change title, font, color in Interface Builder(in red rect below).

[image: Interface builder]

I've seen in .storyboard file

```
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9lO-cw-I2Z" customClass="Label" customModule="AutoRefresh" customModuleProvider="target">
                            <rect key="frame" x="24" y="44" width="327" height="24"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="HelveticaNeue" family="Helvetica Neue" pointSize="32"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.25098040700000002" green="0.50196081400000003" blue="0.0" alpha="0.76206656679999996" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                                <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="style" value="normal"/>
                            </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                        </label>
```

so there fields as "text" or "textColor" don't change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for in Swift 4:

```
@IBDesignable
class Label: UILabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        config()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        config()
    }

    func config() {
        // Setup how you please, e.g. color = UIColor.black
    }

}
```